# Adding Autoplay To Video Element With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have my video automatically play and loop for me when the user scrolls to a specific area on the video element. I'm aware that I can use a JS observer to do this: however, how do I use JavaScript to add and remove 'autoplay'?

**What I want my default code to be:**

```
<video loop muted>
     <source src="/videos/my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
```

**What I want to happen when the user triggers the JS observer:**

```
<video loop muted autoplay>
     <source src="/videos/my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 document.querySelector('video').autoplay = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('video').play();
```

or also

```
document.querySelector('video').pause();
```